# likelihood functions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, model, likelihood

Assuming that a linear regression model is fitted to 5 distinct datasets and that
in all cases the regression line is y = ax+b+e .

Will The likelihood functions are the same for the two different datasets or a difference will appear between them?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you are thinking about the likelihood function: If you have the same regression model but two different data sets then yes the likelihood function takes the same mathematical form. See for example (this is a log likelihood which is just the natural log of the likelihood) equation 3 here: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf

However, the evaluation of a likelihood function is dependent on the data in the data sets. So assuming the values of the data in the data sets are different between the two then you have the same function but would get different values when evaluating the function on each data set. This is because the likelihood function is a mathematical function that relates the model parameters (e.g., slope and intercept) to the data.

Comment: thank you!! i am a bit confused. How can i find the likelihood function of the equation? How can i calculate the σ?

Comment: I'm not sure what equation you are referring to. Equation 3 in the linked reference does not involve $\sigma$. If you are referring to Equation 6 then it gives you the formula and you can solve for the $\beta$s by looking at equations 4-5.

Comment: Do you mean in terms of which of the two variables you use for the explanatory variable? The assumption in the model is that all of the error/scatter about the line comes from uncertainty in the true value of the dependent variable. So the usual design would mean that the independent variable has known values and the dependent variable has some error associated with its values. So yes it comes from the design.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that question. Is there a particular equation you are referring to?

Comment: about the linear regression model

Comment: The explanatory variable (x) does not have to be independent. Nor does the response variable need to be independent. What needs to be independent is the response variable conditioned on the explanatory variable. Basically for any pair of values (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) then y1 and y2 must be independent once you know what x1 and x2 are.

Comment: When fitting a linear regression model b is a single parameter and not a sum of independent variables. The equation for fitting it does involve sums but ultimately you arrive at a single parameter. Honestly, I'm still not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to provide an answer for that. At this point though I might recommend making a new question.